# ios when i change nsstring value in nsdate my app is Crash

Tags: ios, date

I've make a calendar application to show events in calendar for iPad, so I have taken one demo calendar project. In this project, date pass by date picker in event is working properly, but I try to static string value to convert in nsdate and then pass this value is crash datePicker value and after string convert value both are same 
**DatePicker** Value  is =**2014-06-18 14:35:31 +0000**
after **string convert** value is = **2014-06-29 12:00:00 +0000** 
 Here is my code:

```
name=@"ddddd";
        NSString *dateStr = @"2014-06-29";

        // Convert string to date object
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSDate *date2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

        // Convert date object to desired output format
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss +SSSS"];
        dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date2];

        NSDate *dateFromStringf = [[NSDate alloc] init];

        date =[dateFormat stringFromDate:date2];
         NSLog(@"---C%@",date);


        if (!foundDate){
            ahnEvent *newEvent = [[ahnEvent alloc]init];
            NSLog(@"%@",newEvent.date);
            newEvent.date = date;
            newEvent.events = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:name, nil];
            [events addObject:newEvent];
            NSLog(@"%@",events);

        }

        [self.calendar setEvents:events];
    };
```

this is my error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString dateComponent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b0e0d0'
*** First throw call stack
```

:
I am using ahnCalendar Demo 
Do you know where I did the mistake?

This is the link for Demo Project i have implement 
[ClickHere-ahnCalendar](https://github.com/Naglbagl/ahnCalendar)

Comment: Provide more details about the crash.

Comment: Where does it crash, what is the error message, provide the stack trace.

Comment: Hello i have add Error and demo link please help me and if you have any simple calendar demo Link please give me link i want to show event 
 in calendar  for ipad

Comment: how do you pass NSdate in place of NSString? this line i am talking about..date =[dateFormat stringFromDate:date2];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Convert date object to desired output format
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z"];
        dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date2];
```

Please try to use this instead of your date format